# NY Lemon law out of state buyers

Tags: new-york-state, consumer-protection, warranties

If one lives in NJ and purchases a car in NYC, by law are they covered under the NYC/any lemon law warranty? (assuming the car miles etc meets the lemon law requirements)

I read the NY Attorney General's web site and it explains broadly what/what's not covered, but it doesn't explicitly says anything in regards to out of state buyers.

I called the AG office and left a voicemail in regards to my question, but the person did not return my call as yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got a call back from the Attorney Gen's office and they said the car is covered under the lemon law warranty, "It's not where you live, the focus is on the car."

However, if the car breaks down in NJ I must take it back to the Dealer in NY for repairs, If I take it somewhere else for repair I will void that warranty.